# Не ставится Python на Windows XP

Tags: python, windows

Друзья, помогите, пожалуйста, справится со следующей ситуацией:
устанавливаю любой питон(например python-2.6.6.msi), скачанный с офф сайта питона, и при установке получаю следующее исключение.

[image]

Гугл по этому поводу молчит. Может что-нибудь посоветуете. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: msiexec видно поломался, я бы переставил систему.

Comment: а почему не windows installer?)

Comment: Юзай линукс

Comment: Александр весьма вам благодарен. Переустановил windows installer (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/ru-ru/details.aspx?FamilyID=5a58b56f-60b6-4412-95b9-54d056d6f9f4) все отлично заработало.

Comment: может быть не хватает модуля типа win32... который вводится при импортировании модулей типа: import win32timezone: для примера

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте переустановить windows installer на какую-нибудь свежую версию, а если включено автообновление винды, то лучше всего переустановить систему и отключить обновление (практически всегда появляются глюки в системе после обновлений)... у самого стоит ХР сп2, питон 2.6.6, MSVS 2008 - проблем не возникало...